# Always encrypted SQL Azure using Keyvault - Export CMK certificate

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I am encrypting my SQL azure database using Always encrypted with KeyVault.
What I see in Keyvault is, CMK is created in Keys section.
Is it possible to construct a certificate from this? 
or where can I find this certificate of CMK?

Comment: this can be help you. [Get started with azure key vault Certificates](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/)

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Key Vault, you can create different types of objects: keys, secrets and certificates. Always Encrypted requires that column master keys, stored in Azure Key Vault, are Key Vault keys. SSMS creates a Key Vault key, when you choose to store the new column master key in a Key Vault. BTW, what SSMS does when creating a key is equivalent to calling Add-AzureKeyVaultKey.

Having said that, when a Key Vault certificate is created (e.g. via Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate), an addressable key and secret are also created with the same name - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/about-keys--secrets-and-certificates#key-vault-certificates. And, you could use the key, associated with the certificate, as a column master key, if you want. However, I'm not aware of a practical benefit of doing that: an Always Encrypted -enabled client driver (e.g. ADO.NET) would not be even aware the key is associated with the certificate.

It might be useful if you can describe your business requirements and explain why you think you need a column master key to be a certificate.

Please, keep in mind that even when a column master key is a real certificate stored in Windows Certificate Store (not in Key Vault), Always Encrypted-enabled drivers only use the public key and the private key contained in the certificate, and they ignore everything else. In particular, the driver never validates the certificate expiration date, the CA chain or whether a certificate has been revoked. This is by design - master keys protect long-lived data and this approach ensures you will always be able to access the data, as long as you have the master key (e.g. if you create a database backup file, containing encrypted data, and restore a database from it several years later, you should be able to access your data).